# Subset $A\subset\mathbb{Z}$ with the property that $x\leq y\Rightarrow 2y-x\in A$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, integers

> Let $A\subset\mathbb{Z}$ be a set with the following property: $x, y\in A$ with $x\leq y\Rightarrow 2y-x\in A$. Show that if $0,a,b\in A$ with $0<a<b$, then:
>
> $$a+b-2\gcd(a,b)\in A$$
> $$a+b-3\gcd(a,b)\in A$$
> (problem from the $4^{th}$ CIIM (Competencia Iberoamericana Interuniversitaria de Matemáticas))

The first thing I noticed was that for any $0<x\in A$, we have $2x\in A$ and, by induction, if $kx\in A$ and $(k+1)x\in A$, then $(k+2)x=2(k+1)x-kx\in A$ (since $kx\leq (k+1)x$), which means:

$$ka, kb \in A\text{ for all }k\in\mathbb{N}$$

Then I thought about the fact that $\gcd(a,b)=k_1a+k_2b$ for some $k_1,k_2\in\mathbb{Z}$, which seems useful. I also thought about Euclid's algorithm to find $k_1, k_2$, but I couldn't figure out a way to get $a+b-2\gcd(a,b)$ and $a+b-3\gcd(a,b)$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have $r_0,r_1,\dots, r_n$ and $q_1,\dots,q_n$ such that:

$r_i=q_{i+1}r_{i+1}+ r_{i+2}$ for all $0\leq i \leq n-2$ and $r_0=b,r_1=a,r_{n}=0$.

It is not hard to prove by induction that the number $x_m=\sum\limits_{i=0}^ m r_{i}-r_{i+2}$ is in $A$.

This number is equal to $r_0+r_1-r_m-r_{m+1}$

Let $k$ be such that $r_{k+1}=\gcd(a,b)$ and so $r_k=n_0\gcd(a,b)$ for some $n_0\geq 2$.

If we take $m=k$  we get:

$x_m=r_0+r_1-r_k-r_{k+1}=a+b-(n_0+1)\gcd(a,b)$ and $a+b-n_0\gcd(a,b)\in A$.

Clearly this implies that $a+b-n\gcd(a,b)\in A$ for all $n\leq n_0+1$

Comment: the term $r_m-r_{m+2}$ in the sum doesn't depend on $i$, is this correct?

Comment: fixed, Im sorry.